# How to get the covid info of a country with java, JSON

Tags: java, json, url

I am making a java file in which you enter the country and then it shows you the covid-19 info of that country. The site which I am using is https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/countries/
here i want it such that the user enter the country and it adds the countries name to the website eg if the user entered India it should do this
https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/countries/India

Any help would be neccessary, Thanks

Comment: Please show us your attempt. Do you want to do this in plain java or some framework like Spring? How will user provides you country?

Comment: @Smile I use the discord java api (JDA) to get the country, i have done all those part of getting the users feed and then showing the feed, but i am unable to parse data from the site

Comment: hope u can answer

Comment: Please [edit] the question and update with the code you have written to connect to API to get countries

Answer (score 1):

You can use Retrofit to call the APIs

```
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.GsonConverterFactory;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.Response;

public class Retrofit_Example {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    OkHttpClient.Builder client = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("https://covid19.mathdro.id/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .client(client.build())
        .build();

    Service service = retrofit.create(Service.class);
    Call<Response1> responseCall = service.getData("India");
    try {
      Response<Response1> response = responseCall.execute();
      Response1 apiResponse = response.body();
      System.out.println(apiResponse);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }

  }
}
```

You will have to create POJOs from the JSON response coming from the api first and also the retrofit client.
POJO for respone

```
public class Response1 {

    private Confirmed confirmed;
    private Deaths deaths;
    private String lastUpdate;
    private Recovered recovered;

    public Confirmed getConfirmed() {
        return confirmed;
    }

    public void setConfirmed(Confirmed confirmed) {
        this.confirmed = confirmed;
    }

    public Deaths getDeaths() {
        return deaths;
    }

    public void setDeaths(Deaths deaths) {
        this.deaths = deaths;
    }

    public String getLastUpdate() {
        return lastUpdate;
    }

    public void setLastUpdate(String lastUpdate) {
        this.lastUpdate = lastUpdate;
    }

    public Recovered getRecovered() {
        return recovered;
    }

    public void setRecovered(Recovered recovered) {
        this.recovered = recovered;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Response1{" +
            "confirmed=" + confirmed +
            ", deaths=" + deaths +
            ", lastUpdate='" + lastUpdate + '\'' +
            ", recovered=" + recovered +
            '}';
    }
}

public class Recovered {

    private String detail;
    private Long value;

    public String getDetail() {
        return detail;
    }

    public void setDetail(String detail) {
        this.detail = detail;
    }

    public Long getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(Long value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Recovered{" +
            "detail='" + detail + '\'' +
            ", value=" + value +
            '}';
    }
}

public class Deaths {


    private String detail;        
    private Long value;

    public String getDetail() {
        return detail;
    }

    public void setDetail(String detail) {
        this.detail = detail;
    }

    public Long getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(Long value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Deaths{" +
            "detail='" + detail + '\'' +
            ", value=" + value +
            '}';
    }
}

public class Confirmed {


    private String detail;

    private Long value;

    public String getDetail() {
        return detail;
    }

    public void setDetail(String detail) {
        this.detail = detail;
    }

    public Long getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(Long value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Confirmed{" +
            "detail='" + detail + '\'' +
            ", value=" + value +
            '}';
    }
}
```

Retrofit Client

```
public interface Service {
  @GET("/api/countries/{country}")
  public Call<Response1> getData(@Path("country")String country);
}
```

Comment: do we need to download add it to our gradle file?

Comment: yes we have to include dependencies for retorfit, okhttp and gson converter @Teerthjain

Comment: what is than then

Comment: like, what to add

Comment: If you are using gradle you will have a build.gradle file inside which you can add dependencies. You can search for how to add dependencies to gradle. And gradle will download the libraries for you.@Teerthjain

Comment: so, it is pre built, like dont have to add anything to the gradle with this?